# синтаксис второстепенные члены предложения

Tags: определения

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с таким вопросом. В предложении "Это была обыкновенная кукла с широко раскрытыми голубыми глазами, с несколько разведенными руками, с льняными локонами" что будет являться несогласованным определением, а что согласованным. Спор возник такой: "с голубыми глазами, с руками, с льняными локонами" - это несогласованные  определения, а  "широко раскрытыми и несколько разведенными?,выраженные причастным оборотом, " - согласованные. И чем будет являться слово ЭТО( т.е. каким членом предложения) в начале предложения. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

"Это была обыкновенная кукла с широко раскрытыми голубыми глазами, с несколько разведенными руками, с льняными локонами.

Кто?-это-подлежащее

Была кто?- была кукла  -сказуемое

какая?-**обыкновенная** - **согласованное** определение, выраж. одиночным прилагат.

Дальше пошли варианты.

1.какая?-с широко раскрытыми голубыми глазами, с  разведенными руками, с  локонами - **однородные несогласованные** определения, выраженные существительными с зависимыми словами (потому что без зависимых слов определения не имеют смысла: кукла всегда с глазами и с руками, важно - с 
какими)

разведёнными как? насколько?- **несколько**-обст. меры и степени

с локонами какими?-льняными- соглас. определение

(прич. оборот "широко раскрытыми" разобрать отдельно, широко подчеркнуть и как обст.)

*2 вариант*:с широко раскрытыми голубыми глазами, с несколько разведенными руками, с льняными локонами- однородные несоглас. определения, выраженные существит. с причастными оборотами и одиночным прилагат. (а потом разобрать обороты отдельно)

Для вуза больше подходит 2 вар., для школы -1. Смотрите, как объясняет ваш преподаватель.

Comment: Обращался не я.

Answer (score 0):

Людмила,вот ответ на этот вопрос Грамоты.ру.
Вопрос № 285663

> Уважаемая грамота! Вопрос Вам уже этот задавал, ответа не получил. Очень прошу ответить. Хочу все-таки разобраться в споре с ребенком. В предложении" Это была кукла с широко раскрытыми голубыми глазами, с несколько разведенными руками, с льняными локонами" какие определения согласованные, а какие несогласованные? Кукла с голубыми глазами, с руками, с льняными локонами - несогласованные, а широко раскрытыми и несколько разведенными - согласованные, т.к это причастный оборот? Или все это вместе с причастным оборотом несогласованное определение? И каким членом предложения является слово ЭТО в начале предложения. Я вас очень прошу ответить. Спасибо.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

На наш взгляд, в этом предложении три несогласованных определения:  с широко раскрытыми голубыми глазами, с несколько разведенными руками, с льняными локонами. Согласованных определений здесь нет.

Если считать прилагательные и причастия внутри них самостоятельными определениями, то останется: кукла с глазами, с руками, с локонами. А такие определения не имеют смысла.

```
Слово это выступает в роли подлежащего.
```